# What are the disadvantages of using records instead of classes?

Tags: c#-9.0

C# 9 introduces [record](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/) reference types. A record provides some synthesized methods like copy constructor, clone operation, hash codes calculation and comparison/equality operations. It seems to me convenient to use records instead of classes in general. Are there reasons no to do so?

It seems to me that currently Visual Studio as an editor does not support records as well as classes but this will probably change in the future.

Comment: As developers said, it can be useful for Data Transfer Objects (That we use mostly for web development)

Answer (score 20):

Firstly, be aware that if it's possible for a class to contain circular references (which is true for most mutable classes) then many of the auto generated `record` members can StackOverflow. So that's a pretty good reason to not use records for everything.

So when should you use a `record`?

Use a `record` when an instance of a class is entirely defined by the public data it contains, and has no unique identity of it's own.

This means that the record is basically just an immutable bag of data. I don't really care about that particular instance of the record at all, other than that it provides a convenient way of grouping related bits of data together.

Why?

Consider the members a record generates:

1. Value Equality

Two instances of a record are considered equal if they have the same data (by default: if all fields are the same).

This is appropriate for classes with no behavior, which are just used as immutable bags of data. However this is rarely the case for classes which are mutable, or have behavior.

For example if a class is mutable, then two instances which happen to contain the same data shouldn't be considered equal, as that would imply that updating one would update the other, which is obviously false. Instead you should use reference equality for such objects.

Meanwhile if a class is an abstraction providing a service you have to think more carefully about what equality means,  or if it's even relevant to your class. For example imagine a `Crawler` class which can crawl websites and return a list of pages. What would equality mean for such a class? You'd rarely have two instances of a `Crawler`, and if you did, why would you compare them?

2. `with` blocks

`with` blocks provides a convenient way to copy an object and update specific fields. However this is always safe if the object has no identity, as copying it doesn't lose any information. Copying a mutable class loses the identity of the original object, as updating the copy won't update the original. As such you have to consider whether this really makes sense for your class.

3. `ToString`

The generated `ToString` prints out the values of all public properties. If your class is entirely defined by the properties it contains, then this makes a lot of sense. However if your class is not, then that's not necessarily the information you are interested in. A `Crawler` for example may have no public fields at all, but the private fields are likely to be highly relevant to its behavior. You'll probably want to define `ToString` yourself for such classes.

Comment: Are you sure there is the risk of stack overflows? The clone method, for instance, is implemented as a flat copy and not as a deep copy. That means the reference typed properties of the record are copied by reference.

Comment: @MarkusParker the ToString and Equals methods are deep.

Comment: e.g. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOwD4AEBMAjALABQZAbhAgAQQ00C8NmcA7jQII0DeNAQkxbsBACgCUAXwDcZCADp+87swizSuQgE5RCgCoB7AMowEAS0wBzCePVkEcAMYGEAEy5keZBg1wBmAUCeSzgYaRooUPDJMhjyUgdnNwFPbx9/LkzgqIicuMkgA=

Comment: This answer aligns with the official dotnet docs: "For records, the fundamental use is storing data. For object-oriented classes, the fundamental use is defining responsibilities." From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

Answer (score 3):

- All properties of a record are per default public
- All properties of a record are per default immutable

By default, I mean when using the simple record definition syntax.

Also, records can only derive from records and you cannot derive a regular class from a record.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, it's great for Data Types that have no logic. They do reduce boilerplate. The thing I dislike about records is the constructor, which I think leads to a bad programming style. It's not wrong per se, but increases the opportunity to do mistakes.

### Positional Parameters

Let's assume, you have this record

```cs
public record Person(string Firstname, string Lastname);

// Then using it like this:
var someone = new Person("John", "Doe");
```

Looks good, right? But what happens, if someone mistakenly uses the parameters in the incorrect order?

```cs
var wrong = new Person("Doe", "John");
```

This compiles correctly, but is wrong. Now, the more complex your data objects get, you could have multiple parameters in a row that have the same datatype. Even worse! What if someone refactors this object and switches the parameter's ordering? This change could introduce multiple silent bugs and if you don't have a solid test or review base that catches these kinds of errors, it will be very hard to discover what happened until it's too late. (And do you test if the first name is really the first name?)

Of course, you could avoid this by using value types, but that is often just overkill (and there's a better way, keep reading).

### Optional Parameters

A second disadvantage is that you can not easily introduce optional parameters without having to change the code. Take this example:

```cs
public record Person(string Firstname,  string? Middlename, string Lastname);
```

Introducing the optional `Middlename` property will break your code everywhere this type is used.

### Recommendation

What I personally recommend nowadays is to use a language feature introduced after the `record` types: `required` properties.

By refactoring our previous model, we can reduce the chance of mistakes and increase the developer experience (DX) for users using your type. There is some more code to write, it pays off in my opinion.

```cs
public record Person 
{
   public required string Firstname { get; init; }
   public required string Lastname { get; init; }
   public string? Middlename { get; init; }
}

var someone = new Person 
{
   Firstname = "John",
   Lastname = "Doe"
}
```

Now as you can see, this approach requires a few more lines of code, but in my opinion there is a very beneficial balance between boilerplate, DX and creating code that does inherently avoid mistakes. The record will still provide you with overrides for HashCode and ToString and is still immutable and you can use the `with` keyword.

PS: Use your IDE's code snippet to create the Properties automagically, for example `prop` in the Rider IDE.